# How do I display a text or a portion in a TextView as a clickable link

Tags: android, textview, linkify

There are a lot of answers about how to *enable links* in a `TextView`, but I couldn't find anything about how to make [a portion of] text in a `TextView` look like a link with a custom action. In other words I want to *fake a link* because the action isn't important enough to get a button. I don't want it to look like a main action on the page.

For example, in my about dialog I want to show the text "Open Source Licenses", have it look like a link, but launch my `OpenSourceLicensesActivity` instead of an actual URL.

I eventually got my answer from posts by those who were experiencing issues with the above, so I'm providing an answer to this specific question here.

Comment: Just a downvote without an explanation? Thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method below will make the portion of the text from `start` to `end` clickable.

```
public static void makeClickableLink (@NonNull final TextView textView,
                                      @NonNull final CharSequence text,
                                      final int start,
                                      final int end,
                                      @NonNull final ClickableSpan onClick) { 
    final SpannableString span = new SpannableString (text);
    span.setSpan (onClick, start, end, 0);

    textView.setText (span);
    textView.setMovementMethod (LinkMovementMethod.getInstance ());
}
```

The provided `ClickableSpan` lets you handle the click event as such:

```
final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById (android.R.id.text1);    

final ClickableSpan link = new ClickableSpan () {
    @Override public void onClick (final View widget) {
        context.startActivity (new Intent (context, OpenSourceLicensesActivity.class));
    }
};

makeClickableLink (tv, "Click here for OSS Licenses", 5, 9, link);
```

The above should make`here` clickable, launching your activity.